# How to set a hotkey for the 'Ok' button in QInputDialog?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I receive user input with `QInputDialog.getMultilineText(...)`. It has `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons and I want QInputDialog to close and return the entered text when the user presses `Ctrl+S` (AFAIU, the `done()` method is used for it). How do I implement it?

Comment: `QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_S), dlg, dlg.done)` , see http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@e@t@etm_qt-2.3.27@etmQt@etmView.py/84/PyQt5.QtWidgets.QShortcut

Comment: @VladimirBershov 
QInputDialog is a static method, you can not get the widget.

Comment: Use a custom widget? I don't think QInputDialog is *that* useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is no possible to achieve what you want using the static methods provided by `QInputDialog`. You can't install an event filter or something like that. Moreover, those methods are basic convenience functions.

You should inherit from `QInputDialog`, create the dialog yourself and overwrite `keyPressEvent()` to call `done()` when `Ctrl+S` is pressed.

For example:

**myinputdialog.h**

```
#ifndef MYINPUTDIALOG_H
#define MYINPUTDIALOG_H

#include <QInputDialog>

class MyInputDialog : public QInputDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyInputDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) override;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // MYINPUTDIALOG_H
```

**myinputdialog.cpp**

```
#include "myinputdialog.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>

MyInputDialog::MyInputDialog(QWidget *parent) : QInputDialog(parent)
{
    setOptions(QInputDialog::UsePlainTextEditForTextInput);
}

void MyInputDialog::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;

    if ( e->key() == Qt::Key_S
         && e->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier )
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "CTRL + S";
        done(1);
        e->accept();
        return;
    }

    e->ignore();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "myinputdialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyInputDialog m;
    m.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```